Function which returns RxJs boolean observable - emit single value and complete
I have several functions in an angular project which return a boolean observable. Some of these functions could simply return an immediate result, but could also contain nested observables that open confirmation dialogs or fetch data.  What I'm trying to do is reduce the amount of code with repeated .next(value) followed by complete() code.
Is there a way to emit a value and complete the observable (so that we don't have to unsubscribe), say like subscriber.complete(value), or is there a better way to accomplish this with different rxjs operators?
checkClientState = (state: ClientState, assistanceType: AssistanceType) => {
  return new Observable<boolean>((subscriber) => {
    if (state.isValid) {
      subscriber.next(true)
      subscriber.complete();
    }
    else {
      this.dialogService.confirm('Application Required', 'This Application is currently closed. Would you like to create a new Application?')
        .subscribe((confirmed) => {
          if (confirmed)
            this.applicationService.openNewApplication(this.store, assistanceType)
              .subscribe((result) => {
                subscriber.next(result);
                subscriber.complete();
              })
          else {
            subscriber.next(false)
            subscriber.complete();
          }
        })
    }
    });
}

I have tried using rxjs of(value) but it comes back to having to repeat subscriber.complete() for the observable.

Do you need to return an observable? I think returning a promise would be better equipped to handle this use case.

I hadn't thought of that - good suggestion.  With resolve(value) it would eliminate the need for two statements plus I could use async with the consumer.

We can use switchMap and of to simulate the sequence, if state is value, just return of(true) else use switchMap to execute the rest of the sequence.
import './style.css';

import { rx, of, map, takeWhile } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

function checkClientState(state: any, assistanceType: any) {
  return state.isValid
    ? of(true)
    : of(true).pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.dialogService.confirm('Application Required', 'This Application is currently closed. Would you like to create a new Application?')
          // return of(true) // simulate `this.dialogService.confirm` try toggling the boolean
          //   .pipe(delay(2000)) // simulate `this.dialogService.confirm` try toggling the boolean
            .pipe(take(1), map((confirmed: boolean) => confirmed || false));
        })
      );
}

checkClientState({ isValid: true }, {}).subscribe({
  next: (data) => console.log('next', data),
  error: (data) => console.log('error', data),
  complete: () => console.log('complete'),
});

Stackblitz Demo

This is a pretty good solution, but won't the consumer need to unsubscribe?

@DavidAdams Http calls made with httpClient will auto complete, and of will  also autocomplete

@DavidAdams just make sure the dialog service completes, we can use take(1) to make it autocomplete on first emission, updated my answer with the same.

Did not know that about of() - TY!
